# Error compiling in #define

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cryptlib

I am trying to compile the code from Cryptlib. But I go an error a the line 96 of [this](https://github.com/elm/cryptlib/blob/master/misc/debug.h) file. 
 I also got several others error in gthr.h from mingw. 
I am compiling using mingw 4.8.1 under Windows.


The error I got line 96 of debug.h

```
 error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
```

EDIT 1: 
 I changed the file in order to make define static_assert with the line 93. But I getting a new error in the typetrait file from mingw.

```
 template<typename _Tp, typename... _Args>
struct __is_nary_constructible
: public __is_nary_constructible_impl<_Tp, _Args...>::type
{
  static_assert(sizeof...(_Args) > 1,
                "Only useful for > 1 arguments");
};
```

And the error is :

```
error: expected identifier before 'sizeof'|
```

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 should use line 93 branch for static_assert...

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace std` and `#include <string>` somewhere before this header? It is possible that the `string` identifier in the file is confusing the compiler.

Comment: @TheDark Not at all :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just commented the 2 line that had bothered me, the compiler didn't say a word so it's fine.